# Ionic5 | Storage not ready on native Device

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

we are currently developing an app based on Ionic. To enable a new login and to keep the data for a long time, we use ionic storage. In the Android emulation (Android 11) everything seems to work fine. If I install the app on my smartphone (Android 11) my script pops and it breaks off.

The app is an app that returns the next access points for a delivery service. The whole thing works together with a PHP-RestAPI which works with a session. The session as well as access data and other data (the tour) should be saved in the storage. For security the whole AES256 is encrypted (The Values).

Is there a known problem, did I make a mistake?

But there is no active error. So far the problem only occurs on a real device after the bundler.

Here are some code snippets:

app.module.ts

```
imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot({
        name: '__tourenApp',
        driverOrder: ['sqlite', 'indexeddb', 'websql', 'localstorage'],
    }),
    ...
]
```

Datahandler:

Func-Decrypt:
....

```
    const result = await this.storage.get(key);
    if (typeof result !== 'undefined' && result !== '' && result !== null) {
        try {
            const res: string = await this.aes256.decrypt(this.secureKey, this.secureIV, result);
            this.srvUtil.logMessage(`Eintrag '${key}' mit Wert '${res}' entschlüsselt und aus dem lokalem Speicher geholt`);
            return res;
        } catch (error) {
            this.srvUtil.logMessage(`Es konnten keine Daten für den Key '${key}' aus dem Speicher geholt werden`, MessageType.Error);
        }
    } else {
        return '';
    }
 ... Encrypt-Func:
    try {
        const res = await this.aes256.encrypt(this.secureKey, this.secureIV, value);
        await this.storage.set(key, res);
        this.srvUtil.logMessage(`Neuen Eintrag '${key}' mit Wert '${value}' verschlüsselt und im lokalem Speicher gesichert`);
    } catch (error) {
        this.srvUtil.logMessage(
            `Fehler beim Setzen eines neuen Storage Eintrags mit dem Key ${key} und dem Wert ${value}`, MessageType.Error);
    }
```

Version details:

- Ionic CLI: 6.12.1
- Ionic Angular: 5.0.0
- Ionic Storage: 2.2.0
- Cordova: 9.0.0
- Angular-Core: 9.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error together with an expert. The error is in the drivers. There is obviously a problem under Cordova with sqlite. For all following therefore the information that it unfortunately only works with the driver variant "localstorage".

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like [a bug that was reported](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage/issues/168). Apparently Ionic Storage doesn't correctly wait for SQLite to be ready. The proposed workaround is to manually wait for the underlying localForage's ready event:

```js
const localForage = await this.storage.ready();
localForage.ready(() => {
  // use storage
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't make any difference on Android 11. The storage is simply not ready and won't boot at all. Any other Options?

Comment: If it's a timing problem enabling [CPU](https://umaar.com/dev-tips/88-cpu-throttling/)/[network throttling](https://css-tricks.com/throttling-the-network/) might help you replicate it in the browser. Otherwise try to find out where the problem is by systematically removing different parts (localForage drivers, encryption etc.). Maybe try removing all storage read/write on page load and see if the app still works.

Comment: Thanks, but I already know what the problem is. The plugin Ionic-Storage is not active. With .ready() I can wait forever, the storage will never be ready. But the question is rather, why is it not ready. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Which of the two `ready` do you mean? Does the promise reject or just not resolve? Have you tried it without sqlite? Did you install the `cordova-sqlite-storage` cordova plugin?

Comment: I have looked into the config.xml I found that the entry for the storage is missing. The following plugin is not broken down there:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/storage

Can you show me what the entry should read?

Comment: Unfortunately I have not heard anything more about this. I really need a solution to this as the customer is getting impatient.

Comment: I don't think the config.xml is the problem. Does the plugin appear if you run `cordova plugin ls`?